# How IF statement works with AND and OR?

Tags: if-statement, logical-operators, boolean-logic

Suppose that I have the following code in a generic language:

```
a = 1
b = 2
IF a == 3 AND b == 2:
  do something
ELSE:
  do something
```

If a == 3 is false the program wouldn't need to check the second part because  always results false for any value of n.

In the same way with or:

```
    a = 1
    b = 2
    IF a == 1 OR b == 3:
      do something
    ELSE:
      do something
```

if a == 1 is true the program wouldn't need to check if b == 3 because  is always true.

I want to know if the program stops in the first part in these cases.

Comment: This depends on the language you're using. Most programming languages don't evaluate the second part of the condition in this case, but some may do.

Comment: Do you have any reference/docs that shows that? I couldn't find

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Depending on the language you're using the program might not even do the first check, because in case the code gets compiled the whole if-else could be optimized away together with `a` and `b`, so that only one of the `do something` remains in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could very well depend on the language. I know that in C/C++ it would indeed only check b==2 if a==3 in the case of an and statement. I wasn't positive about the or statement, but I just checked by running this and the output I got indicates only the first part of the or statement executes. I'd recommend going through the effort of just writing your own sample to test such questions in the future.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int call_false()
{
    printf("CALL FALSE \n\r");
    return 0;
}

int call_true()
{
    printf("CALL TRUE \n\r");
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    if( a == call_true() || b == call_false())
    {
        printf("TRUE \n\r");
    }else
    {
        printf("FALSE");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
Hello WorldCALL TRUE                                                                                                                                                              
TRUE                                                                                                                                                                              


...Program finished with exit code 0                                                                                                                                              
Press ENTER to exit console.
```